# How do you configure a Sentry raven client in a development environment to not send exceptions and still work?

Tags: python, django, sentry, raven

We are running a Django server and using Sentry to capture exceptions. When we configure Sentry we add `RAVEN_CONFIG` our different `settings.py` files:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat'
)

RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': 'https://*****@app.getsentry.com/PORT_NUMBER',
}
```

We read [here](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/issues/538) that we can just use an empty string `DSN` property. Though when we run `python manage.py raven test` as depicted [here](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/python/integrations/django/) we get:

```
raven.exceptions.InvalidDsn: Unsupported Sentry DSN scheme:  ()
```

The best solution would be that we could always use a Raven client and the settings file would define whether exceptions are sent or not.

Another requirement is that we would like to use the `Client` module and capture exceptions. For this [we have to set](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/python/) some `DSN` value:

```
from raven import Client
client = Client('https://<key>:<secret>@app.getsentry.com/<project>')
```

So not setting a `DSN` value isn't possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Documentation didn't say you *have* to set `DSN` value, there's just an example *how* to set it.

```
In [1]: from raven import Client

In [2]: client = Client()
Raven is not configured (logging is disabled). Please see the documentation for more information.

In [3]: client.captureMessage('hello')  # it's a noop - no error, no capture.
```

It's important to note that you should pass `None` (or nothing at all) as `DSN` parameter and not empty string, otherwise it raises `InvalidDsn: Unsupported Sentry DSN scheme`.

Also, if you don't like that `Raven is not configured (logging is disabled)...` in your logs, you can mute it like so:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.getLogger('raven').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: I thought the "and still work" part of the question meant sending the Sentry info somewhere (like the logs, for example). 

Is there a way to get it to log what it would have sent, instead of the entirely unhelpful "not configured" message (which it could log once at startup)?

Answer (score 20):

> We read here that we can just use an empty string DSN property.

You should not be setting `DSN` to an empty string, but instead in your development settings configuration *don't specify the `DSN` setting* in the first place:

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {}
```

Comment: Editted the question to explain why this isn't possible. TL;DR - we would like to use the python raven Client module which requires a DSN on initialization

Comment: Just FYI: your config might not allow white space, so just do `RAVEN_CONFIG={}`